# How to export non txt data from Colaboratory to Google Drive?

Tags: google-colaboratory

I'm running Colab and I want to save some non-txt data (numpy arrays, PIL images, .h5 keras/tensorflow models) to my drive.

I'm able to save .txt files using this script

```
from pydrive.auth import GoogleAuth
from pydrive.drive import GoogleDrive
from google.colab import auth
from oauth2client.client import GoogleCredentials

# 1. Authenticate and create the PyDrive client.
auth.authenticate_user()
gauth = GoogleAuth()
gauth.credentials = GoogleCredentials.get_application_default() 
drive = GoogleDrive(gauth)

# PyDrive reference:
# https://googledrive.github.io/PyDrive/docs/build/html/index.html

# 2. Create & upload a file text file.
uploaded = drive.CreateFile({'title': 'Sample upload.txt'})
uploaded.SetContentString('Sample upload file content')
uploaded.Upload()
print('Uploaded file with ID {}'.format(uploaded.get('id')))

# 3. Load a file by ID and print its contents.
downloaded = drive.CreateFile({'id': uploaded.get('id')})
print('Downloaded content "{}"'.format(downloaded.GetContentString()))
```

but I can't using it for other types of data.

Any help would be very much appreciated!

Answer (score 3):

`pydrive` supports uploading a file as well as a string -- see [this sample in the docs](https://pythonhosted.org/PyDrive/filemanagement.html#upload-and-update-file-content).

In addition, you can also set the MIME type when creating the file, eg

```
uploaded = drive.CreateFile({'title': 'sample.csv', 'mimeType': 'text/csv'})
```

Answer (score 1):

I came out with the solution:

Say you generated an image on Colab and want to save it to a specific folder in your Google Drive.

First save you image, as if you were on your local machine:

```
from scipy.misc import imsave
imsave('my_image.png', my_image)
```

This allows you to "temporarily" save your image on your current workspace under the name my_image.png, BUT, it's not yet saved to your disk.

What you should do now is upload it to your Google Drive. Here's how to do it:

```
file = drive.CreateFile({'parents':[{u'id': folder_id}]})
file.SetContentFile('my_image.png')
file.Upload()
```

This permanently saves my_image.png inside the specified folder (whose  id is folder_id)

Hope this helps.